# jquery datatables doesn't update the data

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, datatables

I am trying to use knockout js and jquery datatables to display the data in the grid.

All works fine, except when I try to refresh(Redraw button click)  the grid with a fresh data, I am having issues, there is no error, but grid doesn't refresh.

Can someone please help me in resolving the issue?

The code pen for the same is located at : [CODE PEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OBdrjb)

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.dataTable = {
    init: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
  
  viewModel.SelectedC({name:"test1"});
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, $(el));
    },
    update: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var dt = $(el).DataTable(ko.toJS(valueAccessor()));
  dt.on( 'click', 'tr', function (e) {
    var clickedParentElement = $(e.originalEvent.target).parents()[0];
    var bContext = ko.contextFor(clickedParentElement).$data; 
    
    //ko.contextFor(clickedParentElement).$data.SelectedItem(ko.toJS((dt.row(this).data()))); 
    ko.contextFor(clickedParentElement).$data.SelectedC(dt.row(this).data());
    ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(ko.contextFor(clickedParentElement).$data, dt.row(this));
    } );
    }
}


    
var viewmodel = function (gridC) { 
 
 
    var gridConf =  {
  "Columns": "[{\"displayName\":\"Id\",\"field\":\"id\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":false},{\"displayName\":\"Name\",\"field\":\"name\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Position\",\"field\":\"position\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Office\",\"field\":\"office\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Extn\",\"field\":\"extn\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"StartDate\",\"field\":\"start_date\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Salary\",\"field\":\"salary\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true}]",
  "Data":"[{       \"id\": \"1\",       \"name\": \"Tiger Nixon\",       \"position\": \"System Architect\",       \"salary\": \"$320,800\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/04/25\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"5421\"     },     {       \"id\":\"2\",       \"name\": \"Garrett Winters\",       \"position\": \"Accountant\",       \"salary\": \"$170,750\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/07/25\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"8422\"     },     {       \"id\": \"3\",      \"name\": \"Ashton Cox\",       \"position\": \"Junior Technical Author\",       \"salary\": \"$86,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/01/12\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"1562\"     },     {       \"id\": \"4\",      \"name\": \"Cedric Kelly\",       \"position\": \"Senior Javascript Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$433,060\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/03/29\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"6224\"     },     {       \"id\": \"5\",      \"name\": \"Airi Satou\",       \"position\": \"Accountant\",       \"salary\": \"$162,700\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/11/28\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"5407\"     },     {       \"id\": \"6\",       \"name\": \"BrielleWilliamson\",       \"position\": \"Integration Specialist\",       \"salary\": \"$372,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/12/02\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"4804\"     },     {       \"id\": \"7\",       \"name\":\"Herrod Chandler\",       \"position\": \"Sales Assistant\",       \"salary\": \"$137,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/08/06\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"9608\"     },     {       \"id\": \"8\",       \"name\":\"Rhona Davidson\",       \"position\": \"Integration Specialist\",       \"salary\": \"$327,900\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/10/14\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"6200\"     },     {       \"id\": \"9\",       \"name\":\"Colleen Hurst\",       \"position\": \"Javascript Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$205,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/09/15\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"2360\"     },     {       \"id\": \"10\",      \"name\": \"Sonya Frost\",       \"position\": \"Software Engineer\",       \"salary\": \"$103,600\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/12/13\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"1667\"     },     {       \"id\": \"11\",       \"name\":\"Jena Gaines\",       \"position\": \"Office Manager\",       \"salary\": \"$90,560\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/12/19\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"3814\"     },     {       \"id\": \"12\",       \"name\": \"QuinnFlynn\",       \"position\": \"Support Lead\",       \"salary\": \"$342,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2013/03/03\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"9497\"     },     {       \"id\": \"13\",       \"name\": \"ChardeMarshall\",       \"position\": \"Regional Director\",       \"salary\": \"$470,600\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/10/16\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"6741\"     },     {       \"id\": \"14\",       \"name\": \"HaleyKennedy\",       \"position\": \"Senior Marketing Designer\",       \"salary\": \"$313,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/12/18\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"3597\"     },     {       \"id\": \"15\",       \"name\":\"TatyanaFitzpatrick\",       \"position\": \"Regional Director\",       \"salary\": \"$385,750\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/03/17\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"1965\"     },     {       \"id\": \"16\",       \"name\":\"Michael Silva\",       \"position\": \"Marketing Designer\",       \"salary\": \"$198,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/11/27\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"1581\"     },     {       \"id\": \"17\",       \"name\":\"PaulByrd\",       \"position\": \"Chief Financial Officer (CFO)\",       \"salary\": \"$725,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/06/09\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"3059\"     },     {       \"id\": \"18\",      \"name\": \"Gloria Little\",       \"position\": \"Systems Administrator\",       \"salary\": \"$237,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/04/10\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"1721\"     },     {       \"id\": \"19\",       \"name\":\"Bradley Greer\",       \"position\": \"Software Engineer\",       \"salary\": \"$132,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/10/13\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"2558\"     },     {       \"id\": \"20\",       \"name\": \"DaiRios\",       \"position\": \"Personnel Lead\",       \"salary\": \"$217,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/09/26\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"2290\"     },     {       \"id\": \"21\",       \"name\": \"JenetteCaldwell\",       \"position\": \"Development Lead\",       \"salary\": \"$345,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/09/03\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"1937\"     },     {       \"id\": \"22\",       \"name\": \"YuriBerry\",       \"position\": \"Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)\",       \"salary\": \"$675,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/06/25\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"6154\"     },     {       \"id\": \"23\",       \"name\":\"Caesar Vance\",       \"position\": \"Pre-Sales Support\",       \"salary\": \"$106,450\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/12/12\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"8330\"     },     {       \"id\": \"24\",       \"name\":\"Doris Wilder\",       \"position\": \"Sales Assistant\",       \"salary\": \"$85,600\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/09/20\",       \"office\": \"Sidney\",       \"extn\": \"3023\"     },     {       \"id\": \"25\",       \"name\": \"AngelicaRamos\",       \"position\": \"Chief Executive Officer (CEO)\",       \"salary\": \"$1,200,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/10/09\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"5797\"     },     {       \"id\": \"26\",       \"name\":\"Gavin Joyce\",       \"position\": \"Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$92,575\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/12/22\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"8822\"     },     {       \"id\": \"27\",       \"name\": \"JenniferChang\",       \"position\": \"Regional Director\",       \"salary\": \"$357,650\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/11/14\",       \"office\": \"Singapore\",       \"extn\": \"9239\"     },     {       \"id\": \"28\",       \"name\": \"BrendenWagner\",       \"position\": \"Software Engineer\",       \"salary\": \"$206,850\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/06/07\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"1314\"     },     {       \"id\": \"29\",       \"name\": \"FionaGreen\",       \"position\": \"Chief Operating Officer (COO)\",       \"salary\": \"$850,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/03/11\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"2947\"     },     {       \"id\": \"30\",       \"name\":\"Shou Itou\",       \"position\": \"Regional Marketing\",       \"salary\": \"$163,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/08/14\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"8899\"     },     {       \"id\": \"31\",       \"name\": \"MichelleHouse\",       \"position\": \"Integration Specialist\",       \"salary\": \"$95,400\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/06/02\",       \"office\": \"Sidney\",       \"extn\": \"2769\"     },     {       \"id\": \"32\",       \"name\": \"SukiBurks\",       \"position\": \"Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$114,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/10/22\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"6832\"     },     {       \"id\": \"33\",       \"name\": \"PrescottBartlett\",      \"position\": \"Technical Author\",       \"salary\": \"$145,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/05/07\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"3606\"     },     {       \"id\": \"34\",       \"name\": \"Gavin Cortez\",       \"position\":\"Team Leader\",       \"salary\": \"$235,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/10/26\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"2860\"     },     {       \"id\": \"35\",       \"name\": \"Martena Mccray\",       \"position\":\"Post-Sales support\",       \"salary\": \"$324,050\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/03/09\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"8240\"     },     {       \"id\": \"36\",       \"name\": \"Unity Butler\",       \"position\":\"Marketing Designer\",       \"salary\": \"$85,675\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/12/09\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"5384\"     },     {       \"id\": \"37\",       \"name\": \"Howard Hatfield\",      \"position\": \"Office Manager\",       \"salary\": \"$164,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/12/16\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"7031\"     },     {       \"id\": \"38\",       \"name\": \"Hope Fuentes\",      \"position\":\"Secretary\",       \"salary\": \"$109,850\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/02/12\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"6318\"     },     {       \"id\": \"39\",       \"name\": \"Vivian Harrell\",       \"position\":\"Financial Controller\",       \"salary\": \"$452,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/02/14\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"9422\"     },     {       \"id\": \"40\",       \"name\": \"Timothy Mooney\",      \"position\": \"Office Manager\",       \"salary\": \"$136,200\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/12/11\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"7580\"     },     {       \"id\": \"41\",       \"name\": \"Jackson Bradshaw\",       \"position\":\"Director\",       \"salary\": \"$645,750\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/09/26\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"1042\"     },     {       \"id\": \"42\",       \"name\": \"Olivia Liang\",       \"position\": \"SupportEngineer\",       \"salary\":\"$234,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/02/03\",       \"office\": \"Singapore\",       \"extn\": \"2120\"     },     {       \"id\": \"43\",       \"name\": \"Bruno Nash\",       \"position\": \"SoftwareEngineer\",       \"salary\": \"$163,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/05/03\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"6222\"     },     {       \"id\": \"44\",       \"name\": \"Sakura Yamamoto\",       \"position\": \"SupportEngineer\",       \"salary\": \"$139,575\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/08/19\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"9383\"     },     {       \"id\": \"45\",       \"name\": \"Thor Walton\",       \"position\": \"Developer\",      \"salary\": \"$98,540\",       \"start_date\": \"2013/08/11\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"8327\"     },     {       \"id\": \"46\",       \"name\": \"Finn Camacho\",       \"position\": \"Support Engineer\",       \"salary\":\"$87,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/07/07\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"2927\"     },     {       \"id\": \"47\",       \"name\": \"Serge Baldwin\",       \"position\": \"Data Coordinator\",       \"salary\":\"$138,575\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/04/09\",       \"office\": \"Singapore\",       \"extn\": \"8352\"     },     {       \"id\": \"48\",       \"name\": \"Zenaida Frank\",       \"position\": \"Software Engineer\",       \"salary\":\"$125,250\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/01/04\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"7439\"     },     {       \"id\": \"49\",       \"name\": \"Zorita Serrano\",       \"position\": \"Software Engineer\",       \"salary\":\"$115,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/06/01\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"4389\"     },     {       \"id\": \"50\",       \"name\": \"Jennifer Acosta\",       \"position\": \"Junior JavascriptDeveloper\",       \"salary\": \"$75,650\",       \"start_date\": \"2013/02/01\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"3431\"     },     {       \"id\": \"51\",       \"name\": \"Cara Stevens\",       \"position\": \"SalesAssistant\",       \"salary\": \"$145,600\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/12/06\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"3990\"     },     {       \"id\": \"52\",       \"name\": \"Hermione Butler\",       \"position\": \"RegionalDirector\",       \"salary\": \"$356,250\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/03/21\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"1016\"     },     {       \"id\": \"53\",       \"name\": \"Lael Greer\",       \"position\": \"SystemsAdministrator\",       \"salary\": \"$103,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/02/27\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"6733\"     },     {       \"id\": \"54\",       \"name\": \"Jonas Alexander\",       \"position\":\"Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$86,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/07/14\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"8196\"     },     {       \"id\": \"55\",       \"name\": \"Shad Decker\",       \"position\":\"Regional Director\",       \"salary\": \"$183,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/11/13\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"6373\"     },     {       \"id\": \"56\",       \"name\": \"Michael Bruce\",       \"position\":\"Javascript Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$183,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/06/27\",       \"office\": \"Singapore\",       \"extn\": \"5384\"     },     {       \"id\": \"57\",       \"name\": \"Donna Snider\",      \"position\": \"Customer Support\",       \"salary\": \"$112,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/01/25\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"4226\"     }        ] "
      };
 var self = this;
 
 self.GridConfiguration = ko.observable();
 self.Columns = null;
 self.Data = null;
 self.ColumnDefinitions = null;
 self.SelectedItem = null;
 self.Columns = ko.observableArray([]);
 self.ColumnDefinitions = ko.observableArray([]);
 var selectColumn = {};
 selectColumn.targets = 0;
 selectColumn.data = null;
 selectColumn.orderable = false;
 selectColumn.className = 'select-checkbox';
 selectColumn.data = null;
 self.SelectedItem = ko.observable('test1');

 this.SelectedC = ko.pureComputed({
        read: function () {
            return this.SelectedItem();
        },
        write: function (value) {
    
                this.SelectedItem(value);
                
            
        },
        owner: this
    });
 
 self.ColumnDefinitions.push(selectColumn);
 self.Order = ko.observableArray([]);
 self.Order = [[2,'asc']];
 self.Select = ko.observable();
 self.Select = ({
 style:'single'});

 self.Columns.push({data:null, title:'', searchable:false, visible:true, orderable:false, defaultContent: ''});
 var columns = JSON.parse(gridConf.Columns);
 $.each( columns, function( key, value ) {
   var my_item = {};
   my_item.data = value['field'];
   my_item.title = value['displayName'];
   my_item.visible = value['visible'];
   if(value['visible'] === false){
   my_item.searchable = false;
   
   my_item.title = '';
   
   }
   self.Columns.push(my_item);
 });
 
 var gridData;
 if(gridC != null)
  gridData = JSON.parse(gridC);
  else
  gridData = JSON.parse(gridConf.Data);
 self.initialData = ko.observableArray([]);
 self.initialData(gridData);
 self.GridData = ko.pureComputed({
        read: function () {
            return this.initialData();
        },
        write: function (value) {
    
                this.initialData(value);
                
            
        },
        owner: this
    });
 
 
};

function Redraw(){
  var gridConf =  {
  "Columns": "[{\"displayName\":\"Id\",\"field\":\"id\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":false},{\"displayName\":\"Name\",\"field\":\"name\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Position\",\"field\":\"position\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Office\",\"field\":\"office\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Extn\",\"field\":\"extn\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"StartDate\",\"field\":\"start_date\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Salary\",\"field\":\"salary\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true}]",
  "Data":"[{       \"id\": \"1\",       \"name\": \"Tiger Nixon\",       \"position\": \"System Architect\",       \"salary\": \"$320,800\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/04/25\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"5421\"     },     {       \"id\":\"2\",       \"name\": \"Garrett Winters\",       \"position\": \"Accountant\",       \"salary\": \"$170,750\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/07/25\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"8422\"     },     {       \"id\": \"3\",      \"name\": \"Ashton Cox\",       \"position\": \"Junior Technical Author\",       \"salary\": \"$86,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/01/12\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"1562\"     },     {       \"id\": \"4\",      \"name\": \"Cedric Kelly\",       \"position\": \"Senior Javascript Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$433,060\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/03/29\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"6224\"     },     {       \"id\": \"5\",      \"name\": \"Airi Satou\",       \"position\": \"Accountant\",       \"salary\": \"$162,700\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/11/28\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"5407\"     },     {       \"id\": \"6\",       \"name\": \"BrielleWilliamson\",       \"position\": \"Integration Specialist\",       \"salary\": \"$372,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/12/02\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"4804\"          } ] "
      };
  //ko.cleanNode($('#lookupData'));
  
  if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#lookupData')) {
  var dt = $('#lookupData').DataTable();
  dt.clear();
  //dt.destroy(true);
  //$('#lookupData').empty();
  }
  var vm = new viewmodel(gridConf.Data);
  
  //dt.ajax.reload( null, false );
  //$('#lookupData').DataTable();
 
 
 }

var vm = new viewmodel()
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
    th, td { white-space: nowrap; }
    div.dataTables_wrapper {
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
 table.dataTable tbody td.select-checkbox:before, table.dataTable tbody td.select-checkbox:after, table.dataTable tbody th.select-checkbox:before, table.dataTable tbody th.select-checkbox
 {
  
  width:0!important;
  height:0!important;
  border: 0 !important;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<table id="lookupData" data-bind="dataTable: { scrollY: '200', destroy:true, scrollX: true, order:Order,  paging: true, select:Select,  dom:'t,p', columns:Columns, columnDefs:ColumnDefinitions, data:GridData, pagingType: 'full' }" class="stripe row-border order-column" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
</table>
<span data-bind="text: ko.toJS(SelectedC).name"></span>

<button id="btnRedrawGrid" data-bind="click:Redraw">Redraw</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a couple of things wrong.

1. The `Redraw` function needs to be a part of the viewmodel, otherwise the binding does not happen and the button click will do nothing.
2. The idea of Knockout is to bind a viewmodel once, change the values as many times as you want. So the `Redraw` function should not create a new instance of the viewmodel again. Instead, simply update `initialData`, since `self.GridData` is pureComputed observable that is dependent on `initialData`

Here's the corrected JS:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dataTable = {
    init: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        viewModel.SelectedC({name:"test1"});
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, $(el));
    },
    update: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var dt = $(el).DataTable(ko.toJS(valueAccessor()));
        dt.on( 'click', 'tr', function (e) {
                var clickedParentElement = $(e.originalEvent.target).parents()[0];
                var bContext = ko.contextFor(clickedParentElement).$data; 

                //ko.contextFor(clickedParentElement).$data.SelectedItem(ko.toJS((dt.row(this).data()))); 
                ko.contextFor(clickedParentElement).$data.SelectedC(dt.row(this).data());
                ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(ko.contextFor(clickedParentElement).$data, dt.row(this));
                } );
    }
}



var viewmodel = function (gridC) { 


    var gridConf =  {
        "Columns": "[{\"displayName\":\"Id\",\"field\":\"id\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":false},{\"displayName\":\"Name\",\"field\":\"name\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Position\",\"field\":\"position\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Office\",\"field\":\"office\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Extn\",\"field\":\"extn\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"StartDate\",\"field\":\"start_date\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Salary\",\"field\":\"salary\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true}]",
        "Data":"[{       \"id\": \"1\",       \"name\": \"Tiger Nixon\",       \"position\": \"System Architect\",       \"salary\": \"$320,800\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/04/25\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"5421\"     },     {       \"id\":\"2\",       \"name\": \"Garrett Winters\",       \"position\": \"Accountant\",       \"salary\": \"$170,750\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/07/25\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"8422\"     },     {       \"id\": \"3\",      \"name\": \"Ashton Cox\",       \"position\": \"Junior Technical Author\",       \"salary\": \"$86,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/01/12\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"1562\"     },     {       \"id\": \"4\",      \"name\": \"Cedric Kelly\",       \"position\": \"Senior Javascript Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$433,060\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/03/29\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"6224\"     },     {       \"id\": \"5\",      \"name\": \"Airi Satou\",       \"position\": \"Accountant\",       \"salary\": \"$162,700\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/11/28\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"5407\"     },     {       \"id\": \"6\",       \"name\": \"BrielleWilliamson\",       \"position\": \"Integration Specialist\",       \"salary\": \"$372,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/12/02\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"4804\"     },     {       \"id\": \"7\",       \"name\":\"Herrod Chandler\",       \"position\": \"Sales Assistant\",       \"salary\": \"$137,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/08/06\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"9608\"     },     {       \"id\": \"8\",       \"name\":\"Rhona Davidson\",       \"position\": \"Integration Specialist\",       \"salary\": \"$327,900\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/10/14\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"6200\"     },     {       \"id\": \"9\",       \"name\":\"Colleen Hurst\",       \"position\": \"Javascript Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$205,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/09/15\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"2360\"     },     {       \"id\": \"10\",      \"name\": \"Sonya Frost\",       \"position\": \"Software Engineer\",       \"salary\": \"$103,600\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/12/13\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"1667\"     },     {       \"id\": \"11\",       \"name\":\"Jena Gaines\",       \"position\": \"Office Manager\",       \"salary\": \"$90,560\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/12/19\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"3814\"     },     {       \"id\": \"12\",       \"name\": \"QuinnFlynn\",       \"position\": \"Support Lead\",       \"salary\": \"$342,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2013/03/03\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"9497\"     },     {       \"id\": \"13\",       \"name\": \"ChardeMarshall\",       \"position\": \"Regional Director\",       \"salary\": \"$470,600\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/10/16\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"6741\"     },     {       \"id\": \"14\",       \"name\": \"HaleyKennedy\",       \"position\": \"Senior Marketing Designer\",       \"salary\": \"$313,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/12/18\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"3597\"     },     {       \"id\": \"15\",       \"name\":\"TatyanaFitzpatrick\",       \"position\": \"Regional Director\",       \"salary\": \"$385,750\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/03/17\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"1965\"     },     {       \"id\": \"16\",       \"name\":\"Michael Silva\",       \"position\": \"Marketing Designer\",       \"salary\": \"$198,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/11/27\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"1581\"     },     {       \"id\": \"17\",       \"name\":\"PaulByrd\",       \"position\": \"Chief Financial Officer (CFO)\",       \"salary\": \"$725,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/06/09\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"3059\"     },     {       \"id\": \"18\",      \"name\": \"Gloria Little\",       \"position\": \"Systems Administrator\",       \"salary\": \"$237,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/04/10\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"1721\"     },     {       \"id\": \"19\",       \"name\":\"Bradley Greer\",       \"position\": \"Software Engineer\",       \"salary\": \"$132,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/10/13\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"2558\"     },     {       \"id\": \"20\",       \"name\": \"DaiRios\",       \"position\": \"Personnel Lead\",       \"salary\": \"$217,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/09/26\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"2290\"     },     {       \"id\": \"21\",       \"name\": \"JenetteCaldwell\",       \"position\": \"Development Lead\",       \"salary\": \"$345,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/09/03\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"1937\"     },     {       \"id\": \"22\",       \"name\": \"YuriBerry\",       \"position\": \"Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)\",       \"salary\": \"$675,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/06/25\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"6154\"     },     {       \"id\": \"23\",       \"name\":\"Caesar Vance\",       \"position\": \"Pre-Sales Support\",       \"salary\": \"$106,450\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/12/12\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"8330\"     },     {       \"id\": \"24\",       \"name\":\"Doris Wilder\",       \"position\": \"Sales Assistant\",       \"salary\": \"$85,600\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/09/20\",       \"office\": \"Sidney\",       \"extn\": \"3023\"     },     {       \"id\": \"25\",       \"name\": \"AngelicaRamos\",       \"position\": \"Chief Executive Officer (CEO)\",       \"salary\": \"$1,200,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/10/09\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"5797\"     },     {       \"id\": \"26\",       \"name\":\"Gavin Joyce\",       \"position\": \"Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$92,575\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/12/22\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"8822\"     },     {       \"id\": \"27\",       \"name\": \"JenniferChang\",       \"position\": \"Regional Director\",       \"salary\": \"$357,650\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/11/14\",       \"office\": \"Singapore\",       \"extn\": \"9239\"     },     {       \"id\": \"28\",       \"name\": \"BrendenWagner\",       \"position\": \"Software Engineer\",       \"salary\": \"$206,850\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/06/07\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"1314\"     },     {       \"id\": \"29\",       \"name\": \"FionaGreen\",       \"position\": \"Chief Operating Officer (COO)\",       \"salary\": \"$850,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/03/11\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"2947\"     },     {       \"id\": \"30\",       \"name\":\"Shou Itou\",       \"position\": \"Regional Marketing\",       \"salary\": \"$163,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/08/14\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"8899\"     },     {       \"id\": \"31\",       \"name\": \"MichelleHouse\",       \"position\": \"Integration Specialist\",       \"salary\": \"$95,400\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/06/02\",       \"office\": \"Sidney\",       \"extn\": \"2769\"     },     {       \"id\": \"32\",       \"name\": \"SukiBurks\",       \"position\": \"Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$114,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/10/22\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"6832\"     },     {       \"id\": \"33\",       \"name\": \"PrescottBartlett\",      \"position\": \"Technical Author\",       \"salary\": \"$145,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/05/07\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"3606\"     },     {       \"id\": \"34\",       \"name\": \"Gavin Cortez\",       \"position\":\"Team Leader\",       \"salary\": \"$235,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/10/26\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"2860\"     },     {       \"id\": \"35\",       \"name\": \"Martena Mccray\",       \"position\":\"Post-Sales support\",       \"salary\": \"$324,050\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/03/09\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"8240\"     },     {       \"id\": \"36\",       \"name\": \"Unity Butler\",       \"position\":\"Marketing Designer\",       \"salary\": \"$85,675\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/12/09\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"5384\"     },     {       \"id\": \"37\",       \"name\": \"Howard Hatfield\",      \"position\": \"Office Manager\",       \"salary\": \"$164,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/12/16\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"7031\"     },     {       \"id\": \"38\",       \"name\": \"Hope Fuentes\",      \"position\":\"Secretary\",       \"salary\": \"$109,850\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/02/12\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"6318\"     },     {       \"id\": \"39\",       \"name\": \"Vivian Harrell\",       \"position\":\"Financial Controller\",       \"salary\": \"$452,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/02/14\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"9422\"     },     {       \"id\": \"40\",       \"name\": \"Timothy Mooney\",      \"position\": \"Office Manager\",       \"salary\": \"$136,200\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/12/11\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"7580\"     },     {       \"id\": \"41\",       \"name\": \"Jackson Bradshaw\",       \"position\":\"Director\",       \"salary\": \"$645,750\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/09/26\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"1042\"     },     {       \"id\": \"42\",       \"name\": \"Olivia Liang\",       \"position\": \"SupportEngineer\",       \"salary\":\"$234,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/02/03\",       \"office\": \"Singapore\",       \"extn\": \"2120\"     },     {       \"id\": \"43\",       \"name\": \"Bruno Nash\",       \"position\": \"SoftwareEngineer\",       \"salary\": \"$163,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/05/03\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"6222\"     },     {       \"id\": \"44\",       \"name\": \"Sakura Yamamoto\",       \"position\": \"SupportEngineer\",       \"salary\": \"$139,575\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/08/19\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"9383\"     },     {       \"id\": \"45\",       \"name\": \"Thor Walton\",       \"position\": \"Developer\",      \"salary\": \"$98,540\",       \"start_date\": \"2013/08/11\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"8327\"     },     {       \"id\": \"46\",       \"name\": \"Finn Camacho\",       \"position\": \"Support Engineer\",       \"salary\":\"$87,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/07/07\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"2927\"     },     {       \"id\": \"47\",       \"name\": \"Serge Baldwin\",       \"position\": \"Data Coordinator\",       \"salary\":\"$138,575\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/04/09\",       \"office\": \"Singapore\",       \"extn\": \"8352\"     },     {       \"id\": \"48\",       \"name\": \"Zenaida Frank\",       \"position\": \"Software Engineer\",       \"salary\":\"$125,250\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/01/04\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"7439\"     },     {       \"id\": \"49\",       \"name\": \"Zorita Serrano\",       \"position\": \"Software Engineer\",       \"salary\":\"$115,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/06/01\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"4389\"     },     {       \"id\": \"50\",       \"name\": \"Jennifer Acosta\",       \"position\": \"Junior JavascriptDeveloper\",       \"salary\": \"$75,650\",       \"start_date\": \"2013/02/01\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"3431\"     },     {       \"id\": \"51\",       \"name\": \"Cara Stevens\",       \"position\": \"SalesAssistant\",       \"salary\": \"$145,600\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/12/06\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"3990\"     },     {       \"id\": \"52\",       \"name\": \"Hermione Butler\",       \"position\": \"RegionalDirector\",       \"salary\": \"$356,250\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/03/21\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"1016\"     },     {       \"id\": \"53\",       \"name\": \"Lael Greer\",       \"position\": \"SystemsAdministrator\",       \"salary\": \"$103,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/02/27\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"6733\"     },     {       \"id\": \"54\",       \"name\": \"Jonas Alexander\",       \"position\":\"Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$86,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/07/14\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"8196\"     },     {       \"id\": \"55\",       \"name\": \"Shad Decker\",       \"position\":\"Regional Director\",       \"salary\": \"$183,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/11/13\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"6373\"     },     {       \"id\": \"56\",       \"name\": \"Michael Bruce\",       \"position\":\"Javascript Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$183,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/06/27\",       \"office\": \"Singapore\",       \"extn\": \"5384\"     },     {       \"id\": \"57\",       \"name\": \"Donna Snider\",      \"position\": \"Customer Support\",       \"salary\": \"$112,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/01/25\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"4226\"     }        ] "
      };
    var self = this;

    self.GridConfiguration = ko.observable();
    self.Columns = null;
    self.Data = null;
    self.ColumnDefinitions = null;
    self.SelectedItem = null;
    self.Columns = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.ColumnDefinitions = ko.observableArray([]);
    var selectColumn = {};
    selectColumn.targets = 0;
    selectColumn.data = null;
    selectColumn.orderable = false;
    selectColumn.className = 'select-checkbox';
    selectColumn.data = null;
    self.SelectedItem = ko.observable('test1');

    this.SelectedC = ko.pureComputed({
        read: function () {
            return this.SelectedItem();
        },
        write: function (value) {

                this.SelectedItem(value);


        },
        owner: this
    });

    self.ColumnDefinitions.push(selectColumn);
    self.Order = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.Order = [[2,'asc']];
    self.Select = ko.observable();
    self.Select = ({
    style:'single'});

    self.Columns.push({data:null, title:'', searchable:false, visible:true, orderable:false, defaultContent: ''});
    var columns = JSON.parse(gridConf.Columns);
    $.each( columns, function( key, value ) {
            var my_item = {};
            my_item.data = value['field'];
            my_item.title = value['displayName'];
            my_item.visible = value['visible'];
            if(value['visible'] === false){
            my_item.searchable = false;

            my_item.title = '';

            }
            self.Columns.push(my_item);
    });

    var gridData;
    if(gridC != null)
        gridData = JSON.parse(gridC);
        else
        gridData = JSON.parse(gridConf.Data);
    self.initialData = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.initialData(gridData);
    self.GridData = ko.pureComputed({
        read: function () {
            return this.initialData();
        },
        write: function (value) {

                this.initialData(value);


        },
        owner: this
    });

    self.Redraw = function(){
        var gridConf =  {
        "Columns": "[{\"displayName\":\"Id\",\"field\":\"id\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":false},{\"displayName\":\"Name\",\"field\":\"name\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Position\",\"field\":\"position\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Office\",\"field\":\"office\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Extn\",\"field\":\"extn\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"StartDate\",\"field\":\"start_date\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Salary\",\"field\":\"salary\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true}]",
        "Data":"[{       \"id\": \"1\",       \"name\": \"Tiger Nixon\",       \"position\": \"System Architect\",       \"salary\": \"$320,800\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/04/25\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"5421\"     },     {       \"id\":\"2\",       \"name\": \"Garrett Winters\",       \"position\": \"Accountant\",       \"salary\": \"$170,750\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/07/25\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"8422\"     },     {       \"id\": \"3\",      \"name\": \"Ashton Cox\",       \"position\": \"Junior Technical Author\",       \"salary\": \"$86,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/01/12\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"1562\"     },     {       \"id\": \"4\",      \"name\": \"Cedric Kelly\",       \"position\": \"Senior Javascript Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$433,060\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/03/29\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"6224\"     },     {       \"id\": \"5\",      \"name\": \"Airi Satou\",       \"position\": \"Accountant\",       \"salary\": \"$162,700\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/11/28\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"5407\"     },     {       \"id\": \"6\",       \"name\": \"BrielleWilliamson\",       \"position\": \"Integration Specialist\",       \"salary\": \"$372,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/12/02\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"4804\"          } ] "
      };
        //ko.cleanNode($('#lookupData'));

        if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#lookupData')) {
        var dt = $('#lookupData').DataTable();
        dt.clear();
        //dt.destroy(true);
        //$('#lookupData').empty();
        }
        self.initialData(gridData);
        // var vm = new viewmodel(gridConf.Data);
        //dt.ajax.reload( null, false );
        //$('#lookupData').DataTable();


    }

};



var vm = new viewmodel()
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Hi Ray, Thank you for the update but redraw doesn't update the data in the datatable, if you see the total rows is less in the redraw function for the datatables, but the grid still shows all the rows before redraw. Any idea/suggestions ?

Comment: Never Mind, got it, I forgot to update the grid Data in the redraw call. Thank you, thanks a lot. You saved my day. Appreciate it.

Comment: Ah yes, silly mistake. We need to access gridConf instead gridData `self.initialData(JSON.parse(gridConf.Data));`